# Eiffel: How to wipe_out an ARRAY object without recreating it

Tags: arrays, eiffel

Trying to do something like

```
a: ARRAY[STRING]

create a.make_empty
a.put("foo foo fool")
a.wipe_out
```

Do I have to? or is there another way as STRING doesn't seem to have a .has_default

```
create a.make_empty
a.put("foo foo fool")
create a.make_empty
```

[image: compilation error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to use `keep_head (n)`. It keeps only first `n` items, therefore, when `n = 0`, all items are removed altogether:

```
    a.keep_head (0)
```

Another way is to use a creation procedure, for example, `make_empty` as a regular one. It is going to set an array to the state of a newly created one:

```
    a.make_empty
```

However, this approach looks a bit odd. And it can change `lower` index of the array. So, `keep_head` is preferable.

**Note.** `ARRAYED_LIST` is a good alternative to `ARRAY`: it has almost all features of `ARRAY`, is more flexible, has other features, and `wipe_out` among them.

Comment: Thx for the tip, but if you focus on my question is it the only way? To get answers to other people that have the same question...

Comment: @Pipo I've updated the answer with features that can be called on ARRAY objects.

Comment: Many Thanx for all!!